# Derangement with some variable indentical

Tags: combinations, derangements

Question: In how many ways can the number $122345$ be arranged such that no digit occupies its original place?

I know the formula for derangements, but that is applicable only when all variables are distinct. I am not able to proceed due to the identical digits.

Comment: Place the two $2$s, then place the two digits displaced by the $2$s (multiple cases of how many go where the $2$s had been) then place the remaining two digits

Comment: Consider cases:  1.  Both 2's are swapped with another element.  2.  Exactly one 2 is swapped with another element.  3.  Neither 2 is swapped with another element.  By a swap, I mean if a 2 moves to the position of the 3, the 3 moves to the position of the 2.